# R: ifelse statement and seq() function parameters

Tags: r, if-statement, sequence

I am trying to define some options for the sequences of my y-axis in a baseR plot loop. I am trying to achieve this by using an `if else` statement where I define the axis labels like this

```
if(any(y < 100000 & y > -100000)){plotlabels <- c(-20000000, 20000000, 10000)} else {plotlabels <- c(-20000000, 20000000, 1000)}
```

then comes the plot loop and after that I am calling an `axis()` command for the y axis like this

```
axis(2, at = seq(plotlabels), cex.axis=1, labels=TRUE, tcl=-0.3)
```

But this will not work correctly as I get a vector by using `c()` for `plotlabels` and if I print the result I get the following

```
seq(plotlabels)
[1] 1 2 3
```

How could I change the `if else` statement so that I get the correct sequence parameters according to the `if else` statement (-20000000, 20000000, 10000 or -20000000, 20000000, 1000)?

Comment: The statement `y > 100000 & y < -100000` will never be true.

Comment: oh sorry this was a typing mistake here (I changed it). however I will still get the same result for plotlabels...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `seq` with a vector with at least two elements, the function will return the numbers from one to the vector length.

```
vec <- c(-10, 10, 2)
seq(vec)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

You can use one of the following approaches to obtain a correct sequence:

```
seq(vec[1], vec[2], vec[3])
# [1] -10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8  10

do.call(seq, as.list(vec))
# [1] -10  -8  -6  -4  -2   0   2   4   6   8  10
```